# Issue when calling any npm install command on my mac machine

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I am getting error when I enter any command like:

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

or

```
npm install -g cordova
```

etc.What should I do to resolve above issue

[image]

Comment: Restart your mac and try again

Comment: Don't post text as images, and definitely don't post screenshots of your whole desktop